# Cannot find variable in .suscbribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it keeps telling me that "post" is not defined, line 20 in home.component.ts below. Could any of you code check for me... Thanks

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../_models/index';
import { PostService } from '../_services/index';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: Post[] = [];

    constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // get posts from secure api end point
        this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(users => {
            this.posts = post;
        });
    }
}
```

post.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Author} from "./author";

@Injectable()
export class Post {
    id:number;
    author:Author;
    subscribed:boolean;
    created:string;
    active:boolean;
    text:string;
    comments:string[];

    constructor(id:number, author:Author, subscribed:boolean, created:string, active:boolean, text:string, comments:string[]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.author = author;
        this.subscribed = subscribed;
        this.created = created;
        this.active = active;
        this.text = text;
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public static getPosts():Post{
        return new Post(0, null, null, "", null, "",null);
    }
}
```

post.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { AuthenticationService } from './index';
import { Post } from '../_models/index';

@Injectable()
export class PostService {
    constructor( private http: Http, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization','token ' + this.authenticationService.token);

          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          let options = new RequestOptions({
              headers: headers
          });  //  console.log(headers);

        // get posts from api
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/areas/fun/', options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

If you need anymore let me know. Thanks

Comment: `post` is just never defined..did you mean to have the parameter in that function be `post` instead of `user`?

Comment: No, ignore the comments. I took some code that was for retrieving users and transferred them into posts..How would I define post?

Comment: Fixed comments in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because variable `post` is not declared.

I guess that you were trying to do something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../_models/index';
import { PostService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: Post[] = [];

constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    // get users from secure api end point
    this.postService.getPosts()
        .subscribe(post => {
            this.posts = post;
        });
    }
}
```

The problematic line was:
`.subscribe(user => {` changed to `.subscribe(post => {`

Comment: No this is just for retrieving posts from the api, has nothing to do with users

Comment: Fixed comments in the OP

Comment: So, what you got under ```users``` variable, which is in subscribe?

Comment: That was it, had users and not post :D Thanks, will accept answer, in 5 mins